# How do I get a Mono to wait till dependenat fetch method has run

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to implement an export to excel function via a web service which uses webflux as the other api and controllers work well. My problem is that calling the function that generates the excel file is accessed after retrieving data from repository as a Flux (no problem there). I have sorted the results and am trying to call another populate methid via flatMap, I am having a number of issues trying to get this to work and to make sure that the code in the flatMap runs before the code in the webservice to return the file.

Below is the code for the webservice:

```
    @GetMapping(API_BASE_PATH + "/download")
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download() {
            Mono<Void> createExcel = excelExport.createDocument(false);

            Mono.when(createExcel).log("Excel Created").then();

            Workbook workbook = excelExport.getWb();

            OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                workbook.write(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] media = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) outputStream).toByteArray();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("text/html"));
            headers.set("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.xlsx");
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(media, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            return responseEntity;
        }
```

And the code for the exelExport class:

```
    public Mono<Void> createDocument(boolean all) {
            InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("Timesheet Template.xlsx").getInputStream();
            try {
                wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
                Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
                Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
                if (cell == null)
                    cell = row.createCell(3);
                cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                cell.setCellValue("a test");

                log.info("Created document");

                Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> entries = service.findByMonth(LocalDate.now().getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)).log("Excel Export - retrievedMonths");
                entries.subscribe();

                return entries.groupBy(TimeKeepingEntry::getDateOfMonth).flatMap(Flux::collectList).flatMap(timeKeepingEntries -> this.populateEntry(sheet, timeKeepingEntries)).then();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Error Creating Document", e);
            }

            //should never get here
            return Mono.empty();
        }

    private void populateEntry(Sheet sheet, List<TimeKeepingEntry> timeKeepingEntries) {
            int rowNum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < timeKeepingEntries.size(); i++) {
                TimeKeepingEntry timeKeepingEntry = timeKeepingEntries.get(i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    rowNum = calculateFirstRow(timeKeepingEntry.getDay());
                }
                LocalDate date = timeKeepingEntry.getFullDate();
                Row row2 = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(1);
                cell2.setCellValue(date.toString());
                if (timeKeepingEntry.getDay().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH))) {
                    rowNum = +2;
                } else {
                    rowNum++;
                }
            }
        }
```

The workbook is never update because the populateEntry is never executed. As I said I have tried a number of differnt methods including Mono.just and Mono.when, but I cant seem to get the correct combination to get it to process before the webservice method tries to return the file.

Any help would be great.

Edit1: Shows the ideal crateDocument Method.

```
public Mono<Void> createDocument(boolean all) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("Timesheet Template.xlsx").getInputStream();
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            log.info("Created document");

            if (all) {
                //all entries
            } else {
                service.findByMonth(currentMonthName).log("Excel Export - retrievedMonths").collectSortedList(Comparator.comparing(TimeKeepingEntry::getDateOfMonth)).doOnNext(timeKeepingEntries -> {
                    this.populateEntry(sheet, timeKeepingEntries);
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error Importing File", e);
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

Comment: the fact that a) your webservice is imperative and blocking and b) you need to sort / process all similar dates at once (hence need to load the entire file) makes me think it is not a terrific fit for reactive programming. You also have an extraneous `entries.subscribe()`  in there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems in the implementation of your webservice.

### When to `subscribe`

First off, in reactive programming you must generally try to build a *single* processing pipeline (by calling `Mono` and `Flux` operators and returning the end result as a `Mono` and `Flux`). In any case, you should either let the framework do the `subscribe` or at least only subscribe once, at the end of that pipeline.

Here instead you are mixing two approaches: your `createDocument` method correctly returns a `Mono`, but it also does the `subscribe`. Even worse, the subscription is done on an intermediate step, and nothing subscribes to the whole pipeline in the webservice method.

So in effect, nobody sees the second half of the pipeline (starting with `groupBy`) and thus it never gets executed (this is a lazy `Flux`, also called a "cold" Flux).

### Mixing synchronous and asynchronous

The other problem is again an issue of mixing two approaches: your `Flux` are lazy and asynchronous, but your webservice is written in an imperative and synchronous style.

So the code starts an asynchronous `Flux` from the DB, immediately return to the controller and tries to load the file data from disk.

#### Option 1: Making the controller more `Flux`-oriented

If you use Spring MVC, you can still write these imperative style controllers yet sprinkle in some WebFlux. In that case, you can return a `Mono` or `Flux` and Spring MVC will translate that to the correct asynchronous Servlet construct. But that would mean that you must turn the `OutputStream` and `bytes` handling into a `Mono`, to chain it to the document-writing `Mono` using something like `then`/`flatMap`/etc... It is a bit more involved.

#### Option 2: Turning the `Flux` into imperative blocking code

The other option is to go back to imperative and blocking style by calling `block()` on the `createDocument()` `Mono`. This will subscribe to it and wait for it to complete. After that, the rest of your imperative code should work fine.

### Side Note

`groupBy` has a limitation where if it results in more than `256` open groups it can hang. Here the groups cannot close until the end of the file has been reached, but fortunately since you only process data for a single month, the Flux wouldn't exceed `31` groups.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. I have shortened the code to the following statement in createDocument ```service.findByMonth(currentMonthName).log("Excel Export - retrievedMonths").collectSortedList(Comparator.comparing(TimeKeepingEntry::getDateOfMonth)).subscribe(timeKeepingEntries -> {
                    this.populateEntry(sheet, timeKeepingEntries);
                });```  and return Mono.Empty() which works and I get  a complete execution using Mono.when. How would I go about returning the document via a Flux or Mono?

Comment: first I'd avoid returning mono.empty. replace the subscribe in createDocument with doOnNext and return that Flux. then in the controller combine Flux of timekeeping entries with the byte reading part, wrapped into a Mono using Mono.fromCallable. you can use `then(Mono)` for that purpose. return the resulting Mono

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am confused do you mean that the createDocument method should return a Flux of sorted items and then use the doNext to populate the content. I have edited my question above to show ideally the createDocument method.

Comment: @SimonBasie. Thanks for pointer found this in the documentation for reactor https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking. I have put fully working code below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SimonBasie for the pointers, my working code is now as follows.

```
@GetMapping(value = API_BASE_PATH + "/download", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public Mono<Resource> download() throws IOException {
        Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> createExcel = excelExport.createDocument(false);

        return createExcel.then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            excelExport.getWb().write(outputStream);
            return new ByteArrayResource(outputStream.toByteArray());
        }));
}

public Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> createDocument(boolean all) {
        Flux<TimeKeepingEntry> entries = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("Timesheet Template.xlsx").getInputStream();
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            log.info("Created document");

            if (all) {
                //all entries
            } else {
                entries = service.findByMonth(currentMonthName).log("Excel Export - retrievedMonths").sort(Comparator.comparing(TimeKeepingEntry::getDateOfMonth)).doOnNext(timeKeepingEntry-> {
                    this.populateEntry(sheet, timeKeepingEntry);
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error Importing File", e);
        }
        return entries;
    }
```

Comment: this looks good for your goal of using Reactor in MVC ;) **But keep in mind that this is all still inherently blocking!** It is fine for an MVC application since it is still using a thread-per-request model underneath, but if you convert the app to a fully non-blocking WebFlux app, this becomes problematic (you are blocking one of the _very few_ threads that process requests). One way around that is to offset the blocking work (writing and reading the file) to a dedicated thread/pool using `subscribeOn/publishOn` operators and the `Schedulers.elastic()`, as seen in the docs.

Comment: Thanks @SimonBaslé. I have added Shedulers.elastic() as shown in the docs. Would be good if there is a guide somewhere for creating a file and returning it like this. As I see the main problem around this is the input and output stream that has to be used. Again thanks for help.